# Why is the ColorAnimation for Checked state not persisting color after the MouseOver state is triggered?

Tags: wpf, controltemplate, togglebutton, visualstates

I encountered an issue with a `ControlTemplate` for `ToggleButton` I created.

When the button is `Checked`, a `ColorAnimation` is triggered and the control's background changes color. However, if the user enters the `MouseOver` state, another animation is triggered that affects the button's background as well.

When the mouse is no longer in the `MouseOver` state, the control does not return to the color it should be while it is in the `Checked` state. I'm not sure why this does not persist when the `MouseOver` state is triggered.

The `VisualStateManager` portion of my `ControlTemplate` looks sorta like this:

```
<VisualStateManger.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="Normal"></VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundBorder"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                    To="Gold" Duration="0:0:0.3" />
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckedStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundBorder"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                    To="PaleGoldenrod" Duration="0:0:0.3" />
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Comment: I think it is not a good idea to animate same target properties in visual states that belongs to different groups. One of the solution would be to have visual states in different group operating on different set of properties/elements.

Comment: I was thinking because I'm animating the same property it was the source of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My workaround for the issue I was having involved creating a `Grid` that enclosed the `Border`.

For the `CommonStates` I made animation changes to the `Border.Background` and for the `CheckedStates` I made animation changes to the `Grid.Background`.

It achieves the visual effect I was looking for.