# What is the proper way to implement VisualStates for multiple VisualStateGroups?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visualstatemanager, visualstates

This question is a follow-up to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25801126/975724) as well as [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12589636/975724) about how `VisualStates` work in WPF.

Currently, my understanding is that animating the same property within different `VisualStateGroups` can cause problems (see the linked questions).

To resolve these problems, it requires loop-holes to be taken advantage of.  *(Perhaps loop-hole isn't the correct term, but it appears that the solution isn't what the WPF designers intended.)*

### I'm wondering what is the correct way to animate the same property in multiple `VisualStateGroups` without causing adverse side-effects.  If it is not possible, what is the correct route for achieving the same visual behavior for a control?

I was able to find some related documentation at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189093(v=vs.95).aspx#specifying_the_behavior_of_a_control_when_it_transitions_between_states):

> The control is always in exactly one state per group. For example, a Button can have focus even when the mouse pointer is not over it, so a Button in the Focused state can be in the MouseOver, Pressed, or Normal state.

This leads me to a second question...

### How can you provide a visual behavior that should only occur when two specific `VisualStates` are active?

Take for example a `ToggleButton`:

- If the button is **Checked**, I would like to display **Behavior 1**.
- If the button is **Disabled**, I would like to display **Behavior 2**.
- Finally, if the button is **Checked** and **Disabled**, I would like to display **Behavior 3**.

In the above example, how would you go about rendering the third visual behavior?

Comment: You should use Blend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first part of your question, you'll want each state to interact with a different individual object for each instead of hitting the same one with each VisualState, as example;

```
    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
      <Storyboard>
          <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledState" 
                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
          </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
       </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
      <Storyboard>
          <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckedState" 
                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
          </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
       </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>

<!-- Each state interacts with its own object in your ControlTemplate ideally -->
<Border x:Name="CheckedState" Visibility="Collapsed"
        Background="Green"/>
<Border x:Name="DisabledState" Visibility="Collapsed"
        Background="White" Opacity=".5"/>
```

Instead of one object sharing a property change like;

```
<VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
  <Storyboard>
      <ColorAnimation d:IsOptimized="True"
                      Duration="0"
                      Storyboard.TargetName="Background"
                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                      To="White" />
   </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
<VisualState x:Name="Checked">
  <Storyboard>
      <ColorAnimation d:IsOptimized="True"
                      Duration="0"
                      Storyboard.TargetName="Background"
                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                      To="Green" />
   </Storyboard>
</VisualState>

<Border x:Name="Background" Background="Blue"/>
```

As per your second question, A `VisualState` is going to act as a bool in that it either is, or it isn't in that state. To share a declaration of a state you'd have to add a little more finesse with a MultiTrigger or a converter somewhere or something.

Hope this helps. Cheers

**EDIT ADDITION:**

So you also have available to you `VisualTransition` you could employ like;

```
 <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
  <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
      <VisualTransition From="Normal"
        GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2"
        To="Checked">
        <VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
          <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseIn" Exponent="7" />
        </VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
      </VisualTransition>
      <VisualTransition From="Checked"
        GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2"
        To="Normal">
        <VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
          <CircleEase EasingMode="EaseIn" />
        </VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
      </VisualTransition>
    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
    <!-- etc, etc, etc -->
```

So you can play with your different eases, your generated duration times, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is very helpful.  Since you are changing the visibility, the visual behavior occurs immediately.  If I need to have a gradual transition, does that mean I must animate the opacity?

Comment: Nah, you can just set the `Duration` so something like `DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Duration="0:0:5"` or whatever works for ya. The Visibility change instead of Opacity is better performant.

Comment: Ah I guess there must be a misunderstanding.  The `Duration` property actually belongs to `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames`.  Unfortunately, this doesn't cause the **gradual** effect of slowly appearing into view.  To be honest, I'm not sure how WPF would handle gradually switching to `Visibility.Hidden` or `Visibility.Collapsed`.  I guess modifying the opacity is the only way to achieve what I'm looking for.

Comment: Oh shoot, sorry this is what I get for speeding through questions while I'm waiting on builds, anyway see edited answer in just a sec, you just need a `VisualTransition`